# False proof of faithful flatness

Tags: fake-proofs, projective-module

**My false proof :**
Set $A = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ and $B = \mathbb{Z} [\frac{1+ \sqrt{-3}}{2}]$. Then as a $A$-module,

\begin{align*}
B^{\oplus 2} &\cong B \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} A \\
&\cong \mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2 + X + 1) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} A \\
&\cong A[X]/(X^2 + X + 1) \\
&\cong A^{\oplus 2}.
\end{align*}

Thus $B$ is a direct summand of free $A$-module. In particular, $B$ is a faithfully flat $A$-module. Indeed, let $N$ be a nonzero $A$-module. Then we get

\begin{align*}
0 &\neq (A \otimes_A N)^{\oplus 2} \\
&\cong A^{\oplus 2} \otimes_A N \\
&\cong B^{\oplus 2} \otimes_A N \\
&\cong (B \otimes_A N)^{\oplus 2}
\end{align*}

and $B \otimes_A N \neq 0$.

I show another proof of faithfully flatness of $B$. We know $B$ is a projective $A$-module, so it is sufficient to show that for any maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} \subset A$ we get $\mathfrak{m} B \neq B$. Now assume there is a $\mathfrak{m} \subset A$ such that $\mathfrak{m} B = B$. Then

$$
 2B \subset 2(\mathfrak{m} B) \subset \mathfrak{m} ( 2B) \subset \mathfrak{m}
$$

So $2 \in \mathfrak{m}$. Since $A/2A \cong F_2[X]/(X+1)^2$, $\mathfrak{m}$ must be eaqual to $(2, 1 + \sqrt{-3})$. However $(2, 1 + \sqrt{-3})B = 2B \neq B$, which is a contradiction.

**Question:** I know the argument is incorrect. What is the first mistake of my argument?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $B$ is a direct summand of a free $A$-module only implies that $B$ is projective and flat. It does not in general imply that $B$ is faithfully flat.

Comment: Please see my latest edit.

Comment: With your edit, the proof shows more generally that any module whose direct sum with itself is faithfully flat must itself be faithfully flat.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my latest edit.